# What is their legal title?

Tags: inventorship

If an inventor originated with all the ideas, and another individual who is a-part of the development had the role of only analyzing and criticizing the idea(for it's failures & successes) without contributing any intellectual development, only stating the obvious. Aside from the inventor,does that person have any legal or financial right to the patent?

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate concepts, inventorship and ownership.  An inventor is someone that contributes something material that shows up in at least one claim of the patent application.  I tell clients that if they cannot put a finger on something inventive that shows up as text in at least one claim and link this to a team member, then that team member is not an inventor.  This may change over time as claims are added and dropped (particularly when there is a restriction requirement). Sometimes it is difficult to sort out what ideas came from whom when there was a lot of brainstorming sessions and not much documentation so folks err on including an active team member or supervisor as a co-inventor as the patent process is more forgiving of erring on the side of being expansive than erring on the side of leaving off a true inventor.  This decision gets complicated where there are financial consequences within a company or university from adding a peripheral person to be an inventor as there may be splits in royalties et cetera.  It is a recurring problem in universities that have a totally different regime for deciding who gets named as a co-author to a paper than the proper process to sort out who is an inventor.

Ownership starts with the co-inventors but most inventors do their work while under contract to an employer or a client and the ownership rights pass to the entity that paid for the work. Ownership rights can move around later as patent rights can be sold (assigned).

If there is a dispute on who is a true inventor, the patent attorney handling this needs to sort through the process.  But do not be surprised if the attorney errs on being over-inclusive to avoid leaving out a peripheral player that can at least make a credible argument for being included as a co-inventor.